# How to show the title name completely (not truncated) and how to place the menu elements in the action bar at the bottom?

Tags: android, android-activity, action, title

I have two problems:
1. The title name of the activity is truncated. How to show the full name?
2. I have three menu elements, but only two are shown in the action bar. So, how to place the action bar at the bottom and show all three elements? Of course, the title should stay at top.
If some code or another xml file is needed, I will add it.
Because, I'm I new user, I'm not able to upload images, so I have a link to my site.
http://mladen-bojanic.de/test/android.png

Thanks in advance

Mladen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/open"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Kurse bearbeiten">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Einstellungen">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Info">
</item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The title name of the activity is truncated. How to show the full name?

Use a shorter name.

Or, get a bigger device.

Or, do not show the titles of the actions in the action bar.

Or, use shorter titles for the actions in the action bar.

> So, how to place the action bar at the bottom and show all three elements?

You cannot "place the action bar at the bottom". Moreover, you go on to say:

> Of course, the title should stay at top.

This means that you want a *split* action bar, which, on narrow devices, will give you part of the action bar at the top and part at the bottom. You enable this via `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in your `<activity>` element.

Comment: Yeah, I just need a splitted action bar.
Referring to your last sentence:
I put the parameters in the manifest.xml
<activity android:name=".ActivityMenu" android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >.
But it didn't work. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: @Mladen: "But it didn't work" -- presumably, your device configuration is not deemed narrow. Phone-sized screens in portrait should result in a split action bar. Phone-sized screens in landscape, or larger screens, will not have a split action bar.

Comment: It seems that Google has a bug out there: when setting title by code using getActionBar().setTitle(title), randomly the title is truncated! even if there is place! Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Anaseh: Create a reproducible test case and file an issue on http://b.android.com, I guess.

Comment: well I just created a new issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55256